# Need regex to search string containing '+'

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb

i need to search a string containing + like 'abc+xyz' or 'test+1234',
currently I am using 'abc.*' but not able to search 'abc+xyz'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic regex docs will explain that you can reference a special character by escaping it. The following pattern matches on `abc+xyz`.

```
abc\+xyz
```

[A tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) explaining the above.

Comment: yes, this works. I need to modify the search string using this  
   ------>   if(searchKey.includes('+')){
      let key = searchKey.indexOf('+');
      searchKey = searchKey.splice(key, 0, '\\');
    }     --------->   is there any other good way

Answer (score 0):

for finding  regex which contains special character like above situation, just add "\" (back slash)

Comment: It would help to point out where to add that backslash: here it would be 'abc\+xyz'